# Is hoisting ignored in vue2.7?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, hoisting

```
const test2 = () => {
  test();
};
test2();
const test = () => console.log("test");
```

The code above returns an error. The **command** executed is: node file.js

```
 test();
  ^

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'test' before initialization
```

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
    <button @click="test2">button</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const test2 = () => {
  test();
};
const test = () => console.log("test");
</script>

<style></style>
```

But the above code works fine in vue. As far as I know the arrow function should throw an error because hoisting doesn't work, but it works fine.

[image]

Do you know why it works without error?? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, the sequence of events is:

1. define test2
2. call test2
3. test2 tries to call test and you get an error

Step 4 would be defining test, but you never get that far.

In your second example, the sequence is:

1. define a template
2. define test2
3. define test
4. click which triggers a call to test2 which calls test

The difference has nothing to do with hoisting, just with when test2 is called.

Comment: Now that I think about it, that was a stupid question. Thanks for your answer.